# Nested Models Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a nested model but I have a problem:

In new method in TopicController.rb

```
def new
  @topic = Topic.new
  @topic.message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @topic.build_comment
end
```

And now in create I have (1st try):

```
def create
  @cuser = current_facebook_user.fetch
  @topic = Topic.new(:topic)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @topic.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@topic, :notice => 'Topic was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Error for 1st try:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Message with ID=1 for Topic with ID=):
```

I also tried (2nd try):

```
def create
  @cuser = current_facebook_user.fetch
  @topic = Topic.new
  @topic.message = params['topic']['message_id'] #enters nil instead of the message_id
  @topic.comment = params['topic']['comment_id'] #enters nil instead of the comment_id
  @topic.user = User.find(1) #enters correct user_id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @topic.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@topic, :notice => 'Topic was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Error for second try:

```
No Error but Topic.message_id = nill and Topic.comment_id = nill. Those values are not assigned.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `message` and `comment` are defined as associations in the `Topic` model, you shouldn't assign IDs to them, but objects, like this:

```
@topic.message = Message.find(params[:topic][:message_id])
@topic.comment = Comment.find(params[:topic][:comment_id])
```

This only makes sense, of course, if both `message` and `comment` have already been created.

Comment: It says couldn't find Message without an Id. Should I have a hidden field with id in my form ?

Comment: If it's not in the form, it's not transferred and hence not in the params. Your code only make sense if both message and comment are objects which exist before the topic exists. Otherwise the IDs don't exist yet and you need to build the associated objects in your create action.

Comment: So yes, for example you need to include a hidden field with the message_id in your form. But concerning the comment, it looks to me as if it doesn't exist yet, so clearly there is no ID. You have to use create_comment on the topic you're creating in this case.

Comment: message is already in the database but comment it's not. but it's not working for either.

Comment: did you create the hidden field in your form? did you check what parameters get transmitted by checking the log? how did you define the hidden field?

Comment: `<%= p.input :id %>` how can I check what parameters get transmitted? I am using heroku.

Comment: Well, that's beyond this question, but Heroku has many tutorials and I  recommend spending more time reading them. Anyway, you need something like `<%= p.hidden_field :message_id %>`, assuming `p` represents the topic in a `form_for` block (not sure what your view looks like).

Comment: Then it's `<%= p.input :message_id, :as => :hidden %>`

Comment: `{"message_attributes"=>{"id"=>"1", "description"=>"a"}, "comment_attributes"=>{"description"=>"b"}}` That's what I get when I print `params[:topic]` in the create controller. From this how can I get that id ? `params[:topic][:message_id]` is not working

Comment: I see. Then I suppose it would be `params[:message_attributes][:id]`